# Pymssql insert multiple from list of dictionaries with dynamic column names

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymssql

I am using python 2.7 to perform CRUD operations on a MS SQL 2012 DB.

I have data stored in a List of Dictionaries "NewComputers" (each dictionary is a row in the database).

This is working properly. However, the source data column names and the destination column names are both hard-coded (note that the column names are different).

**Questions:** Instead of hard-coding the data source column names, how can I loop over the dictionary to determine the column names dynamically? Also, instead of hard-coding the destination (database table) column names, how can I loop over a list of column names dynamically?

I would like to make this function re-usable for different data source columns and destination columns.

In other words:

"INSERT INTO Computer (PARAMETERIZED LIST OF COLUMN NAMES) VALUES (PARAMETERIZED LIST OF VALUES)"

Here is the function:

```
def insertSR(NewComputers):
    conn = pymssql.connect(mssql_server, mssql_user, mssql_pwd, "Computers")
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
    try:
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Computer (ComputerID, HostName, Type) VALUES (%(computer_id)s, %(host_name)s, %(type)s)", NewComputers) # How to make the column names dynamic?
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        print("ERROR: Database Insert failed.")
    conn.commit()
    print("Inserted {} rows successfully".format(cursor.rowcount))
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you'd like to.

Basically, your multiple insert SQL query will get translated to :

```
insert into table (column1, column2, column3) values (a1,a2,a3), (b1,b2,b3)
```

So as you can see, you'll at least have to make one different query per destination columns group.

Then on the data source side, `(a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3)` in my example, you don't have to specify the column name, so you can have different data sources for a given destination.

On this part, I'd do something like this :

First build a correspondance dict, key is the destination field name, and values are the other names used for this field in the data source tables :

```
source_correspondance = {
          'ComputerID':['id_computer', 'computer_Id'],
          'HostName': ['host', 'ip', 'host_name'],
          'Type':['type', 'type']
}
```

Then iterate over your data source, and replace the column name by the key of your correspondance dict.

Then finally you can build your queries (1 executemany per destination 'type').